# sorting elements while inserting them into vector not working

Tags: c++, random, c++11

I'm trying to a vector filled with a randomly generated number, but the problem is that when I run it I get only 2 numbers after sort.

0
0
0
0
0
17
17
17

this is my code, so can you tell me please what I'm doing wrong

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

class Rand_int {
public:

    Rand_int(int low, int high) :dist{low,high} {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            cout << "Generated: " << dist(re) << endl;
            num = dist(re); }
    int operator()() { return dist(re);}
    int getNum() const
    {
        return num;
    }
    bool operator()(int x) const
    {
        return (num <= x);
    }

private:
    default_random_engine re;
    uniform_int_distribution<> dist;
    int num;
};

int main()
{
    int n=10;
    vector<int> v(n);
    Rand_int rnd {0,20};   // make a uniform random number generator

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        vector<int>::iterator iter = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), rnd);
        v.insert(iter, rnd.getNum());
    }

    for (vector<int>::const_iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++)
        cout << *iter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, did you write `Rand_int` yourself? Because you’re using it wrongly.

Comment: You seem to be under impression that calling `getNum` will return new number every time. It won't. `num` is initialized once in the constructor and never changes. Also what is the point of that `for` loop in the constructor?

Comment: the for loop is just for debugging, I was trying to see if random numbers are being generated, and I'm getting random numbers, but the problem happens with the sort, because I'm only getting 0 and some other number.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you want to start with an empty vector:

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

Second, your current random number generator `Random_int` generates only *one* number in `num` and saves it. What you need is a `Random_int` with a state that can be updated:

```
class random_int_state{
public:
    random_int_state(int low, int high) : 
        re{/* Assignment 1 - use a suitable seed for the random generator.
            * maybe you could use a `time`stamp or a `random device`? */
          }, 
        dist{low,high}, 
        num(dist(re)) {}
    int getNum() const
    {
        return num;
    }
    bool operator()(int x) const
    {
        return (num <= x);
    }
    void nextState(){
        /* Assignment 2 - how do you create a new state? 
        ** what is the observable state of this object after all? */
    }

private:
    std::mt19937 re;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;
    int num;
};
```

Other than that your insertion sort algorithm works fine. Just remember to keep the `vector` empty at the beginning of your program, otherwise you will get leading zeros.

Note that this example still needs code from you, but that's quite easy.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::default_random_engine re { std::random_device()() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;

    std::vector<int> v;

    for(int i=0; i!=10; ++i) {
        int r=dist(re);
        auto it=std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), r);
        v.insert(it, r);
    }
    std::copy(
        v.cbegin(), v.cend(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n")  
    );
```

You code was unecessarily confusing, consider the above. Because the vector is sorted we can use `lower_bound` to find the correct place for insertion in O(log(n)) rather than O(n)

Comment: Note: `random_device` is broken in MinGW (will always throw an exception). If OP uses MinGW one needs to use another seed.

Comment: @Zeta where did he mention he was using MinGW?

Comment: Nowhere. It's just a remark for either other user who use MinGW or the OP himself _if_ he uses MinGW. Since his toolchain is unknown a little bit of extra information doesn't hurt, does it?